# Umi.CMS настройка .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, umi

Добрый день. Не сильно силён в настройках `.htaccess` и поэтому возник вопрос.

В нём присутствуют 3 правила:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.xml$ index.php?xmlMode=force&path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^\/?(udata|upage|uobject|ufs|usel|ulang|utype|umess|uhttp):?(\/\/)?(.*)$ releaseStreams.php?scheme=$1&path=$3?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.json$ index.php?jsonMode=force&path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Можно ли поставить условие, чтобы данные протоколы были доступны только с определённых IP?

Пытался ставить `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =IP`, но перестают отрабатываться внутренние запросы сайта, например **AJAX** не отрабатывает.
Как-то можно разрешить этот момент?

Comment: Третье правило нельзя запрещать, у вас поэтому аякс перестает работать

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

**Ограничение доступа к REST-протоколам**

Чтобы ограничить доступ к REST-протоколам udata, upage, uobject, usel и прочим, достаточно внести изменения в файл config.ini в корне сайта.

Например для доступа без ограничения к протоколу udata используется параметр:

```
 udata.http.allow = "1"
```

Чтобы ограничить, нужно заменить этот параметр на uobject.http.permissions = "".

Список возможных опций:

admin - доступно только администраторам сайта (администратор - пользователь, имеющий доступ к администрированию хотя бы одного модуля).
sv - доступно только супервайзерам.
auth - доступно только авторизованным пользователям.
Для остальных протоколов используются аналогичные параметры. Пример с одного моего личного сайта:

```
 uobject.http.permissions = "sv"
 udata.http.permissions = "sv"
 upage.http.permissions = "sv"
```

**Ограничение доступа к xml и json данным.**

К сожалению для решения данной задачи нет параметров в config.ini.

В итоге было решено перехватывать событие отправки страницы в буфер, т.е. до отправки данных пользователю.

Для начала нужно в файле config.ini включить отслеживание этого события:

```
buffer-send-event-enable = "1"
```

Перехватка события (файл events.php в папке classes/modules/content шаблона, или custom_events.php в системной папке модуля):

```
 new umiEventListener('systemBufferSend', 'content', 'object_redirect');
```

Права на доступ к макросу (permissions.php или permissions_custom.php):

```
 $permissions= Array(
  'content' => array('object_redirect')
 );
```

Сам макрос (class.php или custom.php):

```
public function object_redirect(iUmiEventPoint $oEventPoint) {
    if ($oEventPoint->getMode() === "before") {
        $buffer = outputBuffer::current();
        $hierarchy = umiHierarchy::getInstance();
        $path = getServer('REQUEST_URI');
        $permsCol = permissionsCollection::getInstance();
        $isSV = $permsCol->isSv();
        if (strpos($path, '.xml') !== false && !strpos($path, 'sitemap.xml') && !$isSV) {
            $path = str_replace('.xml','',$path);
            $buffer->status('301 Moved Permanently');
            $buffer->redirect($path);
        }
        if (strpos($path, '.json') !== false && !$isSV) {
            $path = str_replace('.json','',$path);
            $buffer->status('301 Moved Permanently');
            $buffer->redirect($path);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```